# R filter rows : where clause : from dataframe

Tags: r, select, filter, dplyr

I am trying to filter a dataframe in R as follows.

Let mydf be the dataframe having two columns A and B.

Let udf be another dataframe having 1 column A.

I want to do the following.

```
Select rows from mydf where mydf[A] is in udf[A]
```

I am using dplyr and tried something on the lines as

```
T = filter(mydf, A %in% udf['A'])
```

That clearly doesn't work. Is there a straightforward workaround for this without explicitly writing for loop ? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm guessing you want `%in% udf[['A']]` , i.e. the vector rather than the sublist.

Comment: Oh ya! Thanks so much! My (real small) bad!

Answer (score 2):

You could use `inner_join` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
r1 <- inner_join(mydf, udf, by='A')
```

Or using `filter` as commented by @BondedDust

```
r2 <- filter(mydf, A %in% udf[['A']])
identical(r1, r2)
#[1] TRUE
```

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setkey(setDT(mydf),A)[udf, nomatch=0]
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
mydf <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(1:10,2*10, replace=TRUE),
    ncol=2, dimnames=list(NULL, LETTERS[1:2])) )
set.seed(29)
udf <- data.frame(A=sample(1:10,6,replace=TRUE))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply pip data and use the `left_join` function.
Here is a reproducible example for this:

## Data:

```
set.seed(123)
colors<- c( rep("yellow", 5), rep("blue", 5), rep("green", 5) )
shapes<- c("circle", "star", "oblong")
numbers<-sample(1:15,replace=T)
group<-sample(LETTERS, 15, replace=T)
mydf<-data.frame(colors,shapes,numbers,group)
mydf

mydf2<- mydf %>%  
    filter (colors=="yellow")

 mydf3 <- mydf %>% left_join(mydf2)
```